# How to recreate previous activity?

Tags: android, recreate

I have a main activity (let's call it A) and a second activity (let's call it B) which's used to change the language of the app. The point is, when I click the button to change the language I also call `recreate();` and B changes it language. Until here it's ok. The problem comes when I go back to the main activity (A) and it hasn't updated the language because it hasn't been recreated, so, is there any way to recreate A from B in order to update A?

I use this code to translate the app (eng version example):

```
public void btnIngles_onClick(View v)
{
    Locale locale = new Locale("en");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    this.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    recreate();
}
```

Comment: try looking at Intent and startActivityForResult and pass the updated language back to the result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) `Activity B` changes some global settings, accessible via `SharedPreferences` for example

2) In `Activity A` do:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(didLanguageChange)
      recreate();
}
```

Problem solved. `Activity A` *will* call `onResume()` since it has switched into a paused state when `Activity B` came into the foreground.

Comment: I did it and it calls `recreate()` method but the activity language does not change.. :(

`protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        if (idioma.compareTo(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()) != 0)
            this.recreate();
    }`

I've checked that the condition returns true and language is changed, but as I said, A doesn't change its language.

Comment: @Drumnbass how do you set your texts? Do you use localized strings?

Comment: Yes, in fact, the whole app gets translated (even contextual menus on A). The only which doesn't not get updated is A even recreating it, I don't know  what to say, it's kinda wierd, but it's also funny xD

Comment: @Drumnbass Android uses the system locale/language to determine which localized strings to get. How do you change the language? Do you manually change the locale?

Comment: Yes I do, I've edited my post to show you the code which I use to change the language. Maybe I do something wrong, but the app gets translated anyway and I think it has not relation with the problem. But you are the master here, let's see what you think!

Comment: @Drumnbass this is not recommended but anyway, do you check that the locale *actually* gets changed *after* the Activity A is recreated?

Comment: I didn't (watching its value at least), but if at this point I go again to B, it's translated

Comment: @Drumnbass add a locale check to Activity's A `onCreate()` and change it again if needed. You will need some other class to provide the current locale selected by user. Explicitly changing the locale is a kind of "fighting the system" so get yourself ready for multiple checks

Comment: Omg, I'm so sorry for the wasted time. I've actually found the problem. I forgot that I tried to override the `recreate()` method on Activity A (trying to call it from B) and finally I left it empty... after remove that "fail override" it works great! I really appreciate your help. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement `onActivityResult()` in your Activity. This [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) has more information and should be very helpful to you. In a nutshell:

Inside your Activity A, you'll need to create a variable used as a request code, something like this:

```
private static final int ACTIVITY_B_REQUEST = 0;
```

And then, in your button's onClick listener, you'll start the activity using an intent and the `startActivityForResult()` function:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, ACTIVITY_B_REQUEST);
```

This will start Activity B for you. Whenever Activity B finishes, `onActivityResult` will be called. You can override it and implement it in whichever way you need, but it may look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == ACTIVITY_B_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OKAY){
        // Handle this by doing what you need to refresh activity A.
    } else{
        super(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }   
}
```

Comment: IMHO, isn't it a bit of an overkill to start an `Activity` for result just to check whether it has changed some setting?

Comment: @Droidman You're right, it may be overkill. Unless they need information back from the new activity, such as which language it needed to be changed to? This just seemed like the proper approach to me because they wanted to use ActivityA to handle whatever happens when ActivityB finishes.

Comment: well, I'm getting your point though I would rather add some kind of check to the `OnResume()`. Maybe this is just my personal approach since I always implement helper classes which monitor changes of important settings and notify all subscribers that are interested in those changes ;)

Comment: @Droidman definitely. I am still learning, just trying to get some experience putting some Android answers out there. They teach me something new, too! Do you think this answer should be removed?

Comment: of course not, since your example offers a clean and working answer to the question. It's a really rare case where only one correct answer can exist. I'm not considering your answer "wrong" in any way, just shared my personal opinion

Comment: @Droidman definitely appreciate it, I agree 100%. Just making sure that this wasn't *wrong*.

Answer (score 2):

Restart your app:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent
                .FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```