# android: `recreate()` not only this, but the last activity also

Tags: android, locale

I use this code to change the locale of my app programatically:

```
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
       getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
recreate();
```

Works like a charme for this activity and all activities afterwards, but if I use the back-function of my cellphone, the last activity is reused, with the old locale.

Any way to invalidate the last activity or to force recreate on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post solved the problem:
[How to recreate previous activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106504/how-to-recreate-previous-activity)

My final solution is:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!currentLanguage.equals(getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage())) {
        recreate();
    }
}
```

and in `onCreate()` :

`currentLanguage = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();`

(Should have searched more).